# Update MySQL-database with array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I update a database with the values from an array? For example, let’s say we got a database with three tables:

**Meals:**
mealnr(PK), name, sort

**Ingredients:** ingredientnr(PK), name, stock

**Structure:** mealnr(FK), ingredientnr(FK), amount

I filled the database with some meals and ingredients. Every meal consists of multiple ingredients. The chef decides you only need 75g of ingredient x instead of 100g for meal y, so it needs to be changed in the database.  Of course it can be done with SQL-commands, but I want to do it using a form in PHP.

First I made a page where all the meals are displayed. A meal can be edited using the edit-button next to it and based on the mealnr, you can change the amount of one or multiple ingredients for that particular meal. On the edit-page all the ingredient names and amounts are displayed in a table. The amount fields are textfields, those can be edited.

I made this script, but I don’t know exactly how I can update my database with the values of an array. I tried it with a foreach-loop, but it doesn't work.. yet. Can somebody help me?

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost',  'root', '');
mysql_select_db("eatit", $conn);

$id = $_REQUEST['mealnr'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT meals.name AS mealname, structure.amount, ingredients.name AS     ingredientname
FROM Meals, Structure, Ingredients 
WHERE meals.mealnr = structure.mealnr
AND structure.ingredientnr = ingredients.ingredientnr
AND meals.mealnr = '$id'");

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{   
 $new_amount = $_POST['amount[]'];
 foreach ($new_amount as $value) {
 mysql_query("UPDATE structure SET amount ='$value', WHERE mealnr = '$id'")
            or die(mysql_error());
    }
 }
 mysql_close($conn);
 ?>

 <p><strong>Ingredients:</strong></p>
<?php
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Ingredient</th>";
echo "<th>Amount (gr)</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while($ingredient = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo $ingredient['ingredientname'];
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo '<input type="text" formmethod="post" name ="amount[]" value="' . $ingredient['amount'] . '"    />';
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>

<input type="submit" name="save" value="save" />
```

Comment: well the first thing you should do off the bat is stop trying to use **mysql_*** as its deprecated... you should switch to either **mysqli_*** or **PDO** and look at parameterizing them since selecting/updating a table with a variable (that could possibly be user input in the future) leaves you vulnerable to sql injection (its always best to practice the correct way for production environment.

Comment: html form name `name="amount[]"` is `!=` to `$_POST['amount[]']`. should be just `$_POST['amount']`

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML markup you have declared the elements holding the name `amount` as an array by using `amount[]`.

So, in your php code that receives the data it's enough to just refer to the amounts this way:

```
$new_amount = $_POST['amount'];
```

instead of:

```
$new_amount = $_POST['amount[]']; // in fact, this is wrong
```

Your foreach is fine, you should add some checks so that the `$value` actually contains a value that you expect, for example an int, float or not less than zero (or whatever checks you find necessary).

```
foreach($new_amount as $value){
    if($value != '' && $value >= 1){
        //sql statements goes here.
        }
    }
```

Receiving form data this way and then directly injecting the result to your SQL statement is always dangerous:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['mealnr'];
```

If you declare that you expect an integer (as the id's *should be*) before you directly inject the code to your SQL statement you have already written safer code.

```
$id = (int)$_REQUEST['mealnr'];
```

Also, just for the record - the mysql_* library is deprecated. As pointed out in the comments, try using PDO or mysqli instead - really!